# Creating a struct parameter

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct defined as :

```
typedef struct pt {
  int x; 
  int y;   
}point;
```

I also have a stack push function declared as  :

```
void push(point p);
```

Now whenever i wish to call this function, I can do the following :

```
point p = {x_value, y_value};
push(p);
```

I wanted to know if there is a less cumbersome workaround for this. Something which could enable me to do this in a single line. Maybe something like :

```
push((point){x_value, y_value});
```

Comment: Have you tried `push((point){x_value, y_value});` to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, i get the error : expected primary-expression before '{' token

Comment: in c you have to allocate the memory. Constructors in C++ handle this. You need to create a constructor as Tilman states below.

Comment: @user1925405 You have to compile the code as C99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you thought of works out of the box in C99:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} point;

push((point){ 42, 1337 });
```

What's even better, the resulting literal is an lvalue, so you can take its address in case your `push()` function accepts a pointer:

```
void push(point *p);

// ...

push(&(point){ 42, 1337 });
```

[Demo here](http://ideone.com/jubj3j).

Answer (score 6):

Define a "constructor" function:

```
point make_point(int x, int y)
{
    point result = {x, y};
    return result;
}
```

Then

```
push(make_point(x, y));
```

Comment: As a C developer, it's a reflex that I think: do people really not recognize that we live after 1999?